# What should be the automated build steps for a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, msbuild, nant

Every-time I check in, I want to trigger Nant build script to run some tasks for the database in the project in Dev/Uat/Live server to clean db, reload contents of db etc.

What should be the steps as I have never done it before? Is there an article that talks about automated database built steps which you can recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to think twice about having it auto-deploy to live.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question and it really depends on the requirements and what you are trying to accomplish.  You can pretty much do anything you want from a SQL perspective using osql within nant.  I have restored databases, created databases, validated database content, etc using nant.

Comment: Thanks Drew and Billinkc (agree with you,it should be manual step).  Drew, do you have any example or article or blog you recommend that you followed. I am lost to find what the steps should be because 60% of times, I am not changing the databases and working on the C# side.

Comment: I just found this one and it is not bad:  http://www.bottleit.com.au/Blog/post/Continuous-database-integration.aspx.  He created an osql target and sets a script file.  The osql target will run the script file based on properties in the nant script (database, user name, password).  You will, of course, need osql on the build machine for this to work.  Everything in sql server 2008 is scriptable, from creating to restoring databases.  So my suggestion is to do what ever you need to do manually, save it as a script file and use that script file in your build script.

Comment: @Drew I'd vote on that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this one and it is not bad: bottleit.com.au/Blog/post/Continuous-database-integration.aspx. He created an osql target and sets a script file. The osql target will run the script file based on properties in the nant script (database, user name, password). You will, of course, need osql on the build machine for this to work. Everything in sql server 2008 is scriptable, from creating to restoring databases. So my suggestion is to do what ever you need to do manually, save it as a script file and use that script file in your build script.